# Sum of digits using Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

I am a beginner in programming and I am trying to output the sum of digits of the user input using Java.

The code should say certain message based on the length of the digit and end it when user types a blank space.

My code executes correctly. However, it only works on the first input. After the first input, I get an error message.

How can I possibly fix my code, so that my while loops work efficiently?

```
    //scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    //ask user for a credit card number
    System.out.print("Enter a credit card number (enter a blank line to quit): ");
    String userNum = input.nextLine();
    
    
    //length and last char of string
    int len = userNum.length();
    char lastDigit = userNum.charAt(len-1);
    
    
    //initial values
    int sumOfDigits = 0;
    int strNum = 0;
    int i;

    //loops
    while (len > 0) {
        if (len == 16) { //when length equals 16
            for (i = 0; i < 15; ++i ) { //calculates sum of digits
                String s = userNum.substring(i, i+1);
                strNum = Integer.parseInt(s);
                sumOfDigits = sumOfDigits + strNum;
            }
            System.out.println("DEBUG: Sum is " + sumOfDigits);
            System.out.println("Check digit is: " + lastDigit);
            System.out.println();    
            System.out.print("Enter a credit card number (enter a blank line to quit): ");
            userNum = input.next();
        }
        else if (userNum.equals("")) { //when user types blank space
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        }
        else { //when user digit is not 16, nor types a blank space
            System.out.println("ERROR! Number MUST have exactly 16 digits."); 
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Enter a credit card number (enter a blank line to quit): ");
                userNum = input.next();
        }
    }
    
    
    
    //input close
    input.close();

}
```

Comment: "so that my while loops work efficiently" if your code doesn't work, deal with that before caring about efficiency.

Comment: On my computer your code works for several credit var numbers entered after each other. Which error message did you see? Only issue I saw was your program does not say goodbye and terminate.

Comment: You need to recalculate `len` and `lastDigit` after reading new values.

Comment: For better reception of your questions here (fewer downvotes, more and better answers), please always be clear and precise about the expected result of your program and how observed result differs. Paste any error message that you get into the question.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem I can see is that you're not recalculating things from the newly-entered strings. I'd guess the specific problem is that `len` is not recalculated, meaning that you will enter the same branch in the conditional statement on each loop iteration.

Put all of the reading-from-input stuff in one place, and move all the variables you can into the loop:

```
while (true) {
  System.out.print("Enter a credit card number (enter a blank line to quit): ");
  // Read it.
  String userNum = input.nextLine();

  if (userNum.equals("")) {
    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    break;
  }

  if (len == 16) {

    // Derive the values you want from it.
    //length and last char of string
    int len = userNum.length();
    char lastDigit = userNum.charAt(len-1);

    // ..
  } else {
    // Print an error... but allow the loop to execute again.
  }
}
```

In this way, you don't have to worry about forgetting to reinitialize variables, or making sure printed messages are the same to enter another value, and you don't have differing ways of reading from the input (your code contains both `input.next` and `input.nextLine`, for instance).